# "make clean" results in "No rule to make target `clean'"

Tags: c, build, makefile

I am running Ubuntu 10.04. Whenever I run `make clean`, I get this:

> make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.

Here is my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -pedantic -O0 -std=gnu99 -m32 -Wall
PROGRAMS = digitreversal
all : $(PROGRAMS)
digitreversal : digitreversal.o
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
.PHONY: clean
clean:
       @rm -f $(PROGRAMS) *.o core
```

Any ideas why its not working?

EDIT: It seems like doing:

```
make -f Makefile.txt clean
```

works. Now: is there any setting to change so I don't have to do the `-f Makefile.txt` every time?

Comment: Make sure you are using the right `makefile`. It may so happen that the above is named `Makefile` and you also have a `makefile` which does not have `clean` target and when you invoke `make clean`, make by defaults uses `makefile` and not `Makefile`.

Comment: just rename your `Makefile.txt` to `Makefile` without an extension in the name.

Comment: I had the same issue on my mac. For some reason the `MakeFile` was not found by the make command. renaming to `makefile` solved the problem. it is absurd though!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It seems your makefile's name is not 'Makefile' or 'makefile'. In case it is different say 'abc' try running 'make -f abc clean'

Answer (score 7):

I suppose you have figured it out by now.
The answer is hidden in your first mail itself.

The `make` command by default looks for `makefile`, `Makefile`, and `GNUMakefile` as the input file and you are having `Makefile.txt` in your folder. Just remove the file extension (`.txt`) and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the file is called GNUMakefile, makefile or Makefile.

If it is called anything else (and you don't want to rename it) then try:

make -f othermakefilename clean

Answer (score 1):

You have fallen victim to the most common of errors in Makefiles. You always need to put a Tab at the beginning of each command. You've put spaces before the `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)` and `@rm -f $(PROGRAMS) *.o core` lines. If you replace them with a Tab, you'll be fine.

However, this error doesn't lead to a "No rule to make target ..." error. That probably means your issue lies beyond your Makefile. Have you checked this is the correct Makefile, as in the one you want to be specifying your commands? Try explicitly passing it as a parameter to make, `make -f Makefile` and let us know what happens.

Comment: If tabs are missing you'll not get `No rule to make target` error, you'll get a `missing separator` error instead.

Comment: You're right, and as I've clarified, that wouldn't be an issue with the Makefile, per se.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Are you sure you're indenting with tabs?

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -pedantic -O0 -std=gnu99 -m32 -Wall
PROGRAMS = digitreversal
all : $(PROGRAMS)
digitreversal : digitreversal.o
    [tab]$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    [tab]@rm -f $(PROGRAMS) *.o core
```