# make clean results in no target with specific makefile name

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++

I have many makefiles under the same project directory.

The Makefile_prune:

```
OBJS    = main.o
SOURCE  = main.cpp
HEADER  =   Division_Euclidean_space.h  Find_diameter.h Find_k_max.h    Householder.h   IO.h    Mean_variance.h Point.h Random_generator.h  Random_kd_forest.h  Tree.h
OUT     =   rkd
CC  = g++
FLAGS   =   -std=c++0x  -O3 -c  -Wall
# -c flag generates object code for separate files

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC)   $(OBJS) -o $(OUT)
    make clean

# create/compile the individual files >>separately<< 
main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) main.cpp

.PHONY : all
# clean house
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)

# do a bit of accounting
count:
    wc $(SOURCE) $(HEADER)
```

I am getting the error for clean, as you can see below:

```
samaras@samaras-A15:~/code$ make -f Makefile_prune 
g++ -std=c++0x  -O3 -c  -Wall main.cpp
g++ main.o -o rkd
make clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/samaras/paper/rkd_forest/code'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/samaras/paper/rkd_forest/code'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Then I can run `make -f Makefile_prune clean`, which will execute the clean-up, but I want to be single commanded, I mean, not having to press enter twice.

Related answers:

1. [“make clean” results in “No rule to make target `clean'”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182118/make-clean-results-in-no-rule-to-make-target-clean)
2. [gcc makefile error: “No rule to make target …”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834748/gcc-makefile-error-no-rule-to-make-target)

---

Idea:

The makefile actually was used for a C project I had and I just made some changes to fit the C++, maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call `make -f Makefile_prune clean`.

When calling `make clean` since you are not using the -f option it won't call Makefile_prune. Its calling some other file named 'Makefile' which may not have the `clean` target.

Also reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html

Comment: No, there are more than one Makefiles. I did this `make -f clean`, but still it won't work.

Comment: Did you try `make -f Makefile_prune clean` ?

Comment: Correct! I suggest you update your question with that! +1. Guess I am the sleeping one ;) Nice webpage btw.

Comment: Haha! Sometime we all do silly errors. I have found myself sleeping many times!
Thanks for the compliment and for visiting it!

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `make` from inside your `makefile` if you don't have to. And in this case, you definitely don't:

```
all: $(OUT) clean

clean : $(OUT)
    rm -f $(OBJS)

$(OUT) : $(OBJS) 
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $(OUT)
```

This will definitely be faster since you don't have to shell out. Also, you won't have to rebuild `rkd` if you run `make` again. Although, if you want to rebuild it everytime, substitute `$(OUT)` with some PHONY rule (e.g. `clean : build`, and `build : $(OBJS)`)

Also, `clean` and `count` should be `PHONY`:

```
.PHONY : all clean count
```

Lastly, one thing worth pointing out. You don't *have* to manually remove the `*.o` files. `make` should remove them for you. See [Chained Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html).

Comment: Nice answer too, however for the chronological order, I will keep the other one as the selected one, +1!